# Using code from objective c .m file in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

I've been assigned a project in objective C, though i need to add on top of it with swift. I added a bridging header file and can access the methods in my .h file.

I'm trying to access IBOutlets in my .m file although I can't access them (for they aren't public). I can I access these outlets? Or rather, how can I make those properties public/accessible.

Here is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SignUpVC : UIViewController

@end
```

here is the .m file:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import "GuidedContentScreen.h"
#import "SignUpVC.h"
#import "LoginVC.h"
#import "FollowUnFollowScreen.h"

@interface SignUpVC ()<UITextFieldDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrllVw;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtEmail;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
    __weak IBOutlet UIView *vwBgVideo;
        CMTime vdoCurrentTime;

    NSArray *arrayCurseWords;
}
@property (strong,nonatomic)id timeObserver;
@property(strong,nonatomic)AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *containerThumbnailView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)AVPlayer *avPlayer;
@property(strong,nonatomic)AVPlayerItem *avPlayerItem;
@property(strong,nonatomic)AVAsset *avAsset;
@property(strong,nonatomic)AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *getStartedButton;
@end

@implementation SignUpVC



-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    if (self.avPlayer)
    {
        [self.avPlayer play];
    }
    else
    {
        [self playVideo];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appEnteredForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appEnteredBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];

}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
//        [self.avPlayer removeTimeObserver:self.timeObserver];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
    [self.avPlayer pause];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Here is my bridging header file:

```
#import "SignUpVC.h"
```

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to access outlets that were declared in a *Swift* file from an Objective-C one? If so, do you have permission to modify the Swift file?

Comment: Could you post some code to find the problem, you can make those properties by adding them in ".h" file

Comment: @NRitH I am accessing outlets that were declared in Objective C file (eg. <SignUp.m>) although that is the implementation, not the .h file.

Comment: @QuocLe I edited the post. I'm looking to save the text input of txtUsername in my SignUpVC.m

Comment: Move the declarations into the .h?

Comment: You can declare a func in .h file like "- (NSString *)getUserName;" and implement it on .m file by return the text, so you can save it. Or you move the declarations as @PhillipMills

Comment: Even after declaring an IBoutlet in my .h file, I still couldn't access it. Is it because it's not initialized? @PhillipMills